# jQueryUI append to accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

According to the docs for 1.10, the following code (also on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aZzeE/1/)) for appending items to an accordion upon drop should work.

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion();

$( "#accordionContainer" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "<h3>New Item</h3>" ).appendTo( "#accordion" );
        $( "<div>New Description</div>" ).appendTo( "#accordion" );
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "refresh" );
    }
});
```

It doesn't. The appended h3 and divs get appended to the wrong object even though I explicitly specify where I want to add them.

There's a jsFiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/a6rCu/) that accompanies the documentation that shows the functionality in action, but it's too long and complex for a newbie to figure out what's different. I must be making a simple mistake. Right? Any ideas what it is?

Isn't there a way to have the accordion be both an accordion and droppable? How do I then specify the proper "this" as the target for the append?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this for less than ui version 1.10:-

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6gp4g/)

```
$(function () {
    $(".draggable").draggable({
        revert: false,
        helper: "clone"
    });
    $("#accordion").accordion();
    $("#accordionContainer").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {

            $("<h3>New Item</h3>").appendTo("#accordion");
            $("<div>New Description</div>").appendTo("#accordion");
            $("#accordion").accordion('destroy').accordion(); //<-- Here is the destruction and recreation
        }
    });


});
```

For ui version 1.10 refresh works

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9qGX8/)

```
$(function () {
    $(".draggable").draggable({
        revert: false,
        helper: "clone"
    });
    $("#accordion").accordion();
    $("#accordionContainer").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {

            $("<h3>New Item</h3>").appendTo("#accordion");
            $("<div>New Description</div>").appendTo("#accordion");
            $("#accordion").accordion('refresh'); //<-- Just a refresh
        }
    });


});
```

Comment: Thanks, that clarified it! I didn't realize that 2.0 was 1.10. That and the differences between ("#accordion").destroy() and ('#accordion').accordion("destroy") and ("#accordion").refresh() and ("#accordion").accordion("refresh") did me in.